# reference key insertion in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i've 2 tables structure line show in image.

```
NG_SCHOOL.PHONE_ID is a foreign key to NG_PHONE_NUMBER.PHONE_NUMBER_ID, as shown in the schema.
```

[image]

now i want to insert data in table using following query

```
INSERT INTO ng_school (SCHOOL_ID, SCHOOL_SYSTEM_ID, NAME, ZIP, CITY, PHONE,  LEAGUE_NAME, MINIMUM_GRADE_ID, MAXIMUM_GRADE_ID) VALUES ('testSchoolA','testSchoolSystem1','Elementary School A','90210','City of Los Angeles','213 555 1000','School A Athletic','K','GRADE6');
```

but it gives error

```
Error Code: 1054 - Unknown column 'PHONE' in 'field list'
```

how to insert this data into table?

Comment: As a side note I would use integer or BIGINT as datatype for the primary key columns. Even though that's not obligatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your query, you are trying to insert a phone number in a column that doesn't exist in the table `ng_school`. `ng_school` only contains a REFERENCE to a phone number(`phone_id`) , but not the phone number itself.

What you'll need to do is insert the phone number first in `ng_phone_number`, get the `PHONE_NUMBER_ID` value and insert that in `ng_school`.

In short:

1/ `INSERT INTO ng_phone_number ....`

2/ `SELECT LAST PHONE_NUMBER_ID or LAST_INSERT_ID()`

3/ `INSERT INTO ng_school(PHONE_ID) VALUES ([phone_number_id goes here])`

Comment: is there any other way run exact query as i mentioned?

Comment: my dump contains same thousand of query.but while restore this file into database gives similar types of error.

Comment: Add a column named "PHONE" in table `ng_school`. Fixed :)

Comment: i don't know how to insert single query in to two tables or how this query will work.

Comment: If you add the column `Phone` in table `ng_school` your query will work.

Comment: can i think about trigger so same query will execute on those tables.

Comment: You are asking to do something that is impossible. You cannot add data to a column that does not exist. You can solve your problem using the principle I explained above (in a stored procedure or not) or add the required column.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27847/discussion-between-dev-and-uw-concept)

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO ng_school (SCHOOL_ID, SCHOOL_SYSTEM_ID, NAME, ZIP, CITY, **PHONE**,  LEAGUE_NAME, MINIMUM_GRADE_ID, MAXIMUM_GRADE_ID) VALUES ('testSchoolA','testSchoolSystem1','Elementary School A','90210','City of Los Angeles','213 555 1000','School A Athletic','K','GRADE6');
```

Cause you don't have phone column in your table.. it's **PHONE_ID**

Comment: i want insert phone data in second table.